# How to transfer my PDF files from my PC to my iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf, ebook, pdf-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App for reading PDF files](https://superuser.com/questions/47900/iphone-app-for-reading-pdf-files)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App for reading PDF files](https://superuser.com/questions/47900/iphone-app-for-reading-pdf-files)

I have about 10 PDF files on my PC, and I'd like to find a way to transfer to my iPhone.  What is a good way?

It is possible to email myself a PDF file to gmail and then use iPhone to read the PDF file. (the email program on iPhone lets users open up a PDF file, so there is already a default PDF reader built in).

But I wonder how to transfer those 10 PDF files all from the PC to the iPhone and have a folder in the iPhone? There seems to be no default app to do that? If possible, I'd like to use the default PDF reader instead of a third party one, as the default one is probably more standard compliant.

Also, if the PDF has 200 pages, there seems to be no easy way to jump to page 120 or bookmark a page.

Would there be such a way?

Comment: duplicate (at least you should find answers to your question on it): http://superuser.com/questions/47900/iphone-app-for-reading-pdf-files